# How to divide tinymce text in React into sections and change only these sections onEditorChange to send them on backend?

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I have a React app which has a TinyMCE instance and upon changing specific sections on editor I want to save them on the backend, only the ones that have been changed. Is it possible to achieve something like that? In vanillajs and html you would have different `divs` with `ids` and you could be able to get a reference on them and change the corresponding part. But in React it is not the same.

What I have tried is to render the text coming from the backend into the editor by using a state variable that has these sections as a dictionary but now I want upon changing only one section to change the corresponding value. what I want to derive is the section name to update the server ( and the corresponding key value pair in the state var). In the example I provided the html content of each section is small but in a real app it can be big. The model is a dictionary which has as keys the section names and as value an object with an id and the html value like this:

```
{ 
  header: { section_id: 2, value: "<h1> This is the header </h1>"},
  body: { section_id: 1, value: "<p>Body content</p>" }
  
  ...
}

function MyComponent() {
  // here is the state var that I am taking from the backend
 // and want to update it according to user changes 
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    header: { section_id: 2, value: "<h1>This is the header</h1>" },
    body: { section_id: 1, value: "<p>Body</p>" }
  });

  const editorValue = Object.values(value)
    .map((v) => v.value)
    .join("<br/>");

  return (
    <Editor
      value={editorValue}
       onEditorChange={(newValue, editor) => {
       // here I would like to get the section part which I am updating somehow
       setValue(newValue);
     }}
    />
  );
}
```

Is there any way to get the section reference somehow according to my attempt or another approach I could follow to achieve the same goal?

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-brown-1lygrf?file=/src/App.js:107-512)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did in the end is the following:

I used the dictionary to loop over the values I have and create as many editors as the values I have inside the dictionary. With this way, I can pass the key which is the section I am changing dynamically and I know which section I am updating so I can send the changed text on the backend to save it separately.

```
const [editorValue, setEditorValue] = useState({
    header: { section_id: 2, value: "<h1>This is the header</h1>" },
    body: { section_id: 1, value: "<p>This is the body</p>" }
  });

const handleEditorChange = (value, editor, key) => {
    setEditorValue((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [key]: { ...prevState[key], value }
    }));
  };

  return Object.entries(editorValue).map(([key, value]) => (
    <Editor
      inline
      menubar={false}
      value={value.value}
      onEditorChange={(value, editor) => handleEditorChange(value, editor, key)}
    />
  ));
```

I have updated also the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-brown-1lygrf?file=/src/App.js:134-319) to include my solution in case someone has the same issue in the future.